# Не работает selenium-wire python

Tags: python, selenium, chromedriver

я пытаюсь подключить прокси с авторизацией в selenium-wire. Но при запуске кода возникает ошибка:

```
127.0.0.1:50498: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/server.py", line 113, in handle
    root_layer()
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/modes/http_proxy.py", line 23, in __call__
    layer()
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/tls.py", line 285, in __call__
    layer()
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http1.py", line 100, in __call__
    layer()
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py", line 206, in __call__
    if not self._process_flow(flow):
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py", line 270, in _process_flow
    if self.mode is HTTPMode.upstream and self.should_bypass_upstream_proxy(f.request):
  File "/home/GorkiiOgurec/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/seleniumwire/thirdparty/mitmproxy/server/protocol/http.py", line 556, in should_bypass_upstream_proxy
    no_proxy = int(port[0]) == request.port
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Вот код:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import time
import json
import os

class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('-start-maximized')

        ua = UserAgent().random
        options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={ua}')

        proxy_options = {
                'proxy': {
                    'http': 'http://login:pass@api:port',
                    'https': 'https://login:pass@api:port'
                    }
                }

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
                executable_path=f'{os.getcwd()}/chromedriver',
                options=options,
                seleniumwire_options=proxy_options
                )

    def test(self):
        self.driver.get('https://2ip.ru')
        time.sleep(30)

t = Test()
t.test()
```

Comment: вот здесь 'http': 'http://login:pass@api:port', должны быть реальные данные типа 'http': f'http://{proxy_username}:{proxy_password}@185.199.229.156:7492', вы либо забыли это исправить, но ошибка говорит. что не может распознать число в десятичной системе.

Comment: @nexoma я специально убрал настоящие данные. Вы не знаете как решить эту ошибку?

Comment: я же написал - ошибка говорит. что не может распознать число в десятичной системе.   проверьте, правильно ли вы передали номер порта и ip-адрес, у вас там нет цифр.